# Get rid of unigrams in a list if contained within bigrams or trigrams python

Tags: python-3.x, list, n-gram

Let's say I have a list of n-grams, and I want to get rid of any unigrams only if they are already contained in a bigram or trigram within the list.

For example:

```
ngram_list = ["apple cider", "apple",  "cat man", "cat", "batman", "bat"]
```

What I would like to end up with is:

```
ngram_list = ["apple cider", "cat man", "batman", "bat"]
```

In the result "apple" is removed because it is contained in the bigram "apple cider" and "cat" is removed because it is contained in bigram "cat man" but "bat" remains because even though "bat" is in "batman", "batman" is not a bigram or trigram.

The way I was thinking of approaching this was to set aside just the unigrams, loop through them, and perform a search for each unigram on a separate list containing just the bigrams and trigrams... But I'm just wondering what's the most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first iterate through all input ngrams separating the unigrams from the rest and build up a list of buzz "seen" unigrams from the (n+1)-grams, then I would filter up the input with it:

```
def clean_up(ngrams):
    seen = set()
    for ngram in ngrams:
        if ' ' in ngram:
            seen = seen.union(set(ngram.split()))
    return [ngram for ngram in ngrams if ngram not in seen]


print(clean_up(ngram_list))
# ['apple cider', 'cat man', 'batman', 'bat']
```

---

If you were to have many more (n+1)-grams than unigrams, you may get faster by saving some results from the first iteration:

```
def clean_up2(ngrams):
    unigrams = []
    nplus1grams = []
    seen = set()
    for ngram in ngrams:
        if ' ' in ngram:
            nplus1grams.append(ngram)
            seen = seen.union(set(ngram.split()))
        else:
            unigrams.append(ngram)
    return nplus1grams + [unigram for unigram in unigrams if unigram not in seen]


print(clean_up(ngram_list))
# ['apple cider', 'cat man', 'batman', 'bat']
```

Although this would require some more memory and it will not (in general) preserve the order of the input, but it will place all the (surviving) unigrams at the end.